# Object does not move properly with Armature

Tags: animation, armature, bones, pose-mode

I created an Armature for this Elephant where I put at the tail of every active bone a nondeformer Controler. Now I got the problem that the Armature seems to look good but does in Pose mode strange stuff. So basicly my Mesh isn't working how it should be.

Is there a trick or a setting which can solve my problem?

[image]

[image][image]

Comment: Sharing your blend file would be helpful https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Did you set a proper chain lenght on every IK constraint? If not, every IK constraint will act along the whole armature, leading to unexpected behaviours.

Comment: I added the File and yes, I set the chain lenght....hopefully to a usefull length :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your weight painting is bad.
With your mesh active and your armature selected go to weight paint mode:

[image]

ctrl + click each bone you want to paint the weights on, then paint it with the draw tool:

[image]

When finished, your rig should behave better:

[image]